# метод soup.find не находит вложение

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Был похожий вопрос, но не то немного

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
URL = 'https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/HKEX-9988/'
HTML = requests.get(URL)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML.content, 'html.parser')
 
price = soup.find('div', class_='tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last')
print(price)
```

На выходе получаю:

```
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"></div>
```

Что хотелось бы получить:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда парсишь html span еще не добавлен, поэтому и не выводит. Попробуй так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


url = "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/HKEX-9988/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
HTML = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(class_ = "tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last")

#price = soup.find(class_ = "tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last").find("span").string
#результат - 219.8

browser.quit()

print(price)
```

Comment: Да, получилось! Спасибо!